# How to aggregate relationship counts in Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have account and transaction nodes, and a received_from relationship between them. Given a scenario where account A has received 1 transaction from B and C has received 10 transactions from B. I want to visualize this not with 10 lines from B to C, but with a thicker arrow and a count label.

How would I write such a query so that I get the count of each relationship type between nodes instead of a list of all the relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming each account node has an `acct_id` property being indexed using `CREATE INDEX ON :Account(acct_id)`.

You could use a Cypher query to aggregate relationship counts:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (start:Account {acct_id:'C'})-[r:RECEIVED_FROM]->(end:Account {acct_id:'B'})
RETURN start.acct_id, end.acct_id, type(r) as type, count(r) as thickness
```

N.B. in case you don't want a result row if there is no relationship between `start` and `end` you can omit `OPTIONAL`. With `OPTIONAL` the thickness for non related nodes is 0.